The Spyder debugger stops at breakpoints in the current file (i.e. where I start the debugging session), not in another file
I usually use pycharm and liclipse to debug python projects.
I'd like to test spyder, which I installed today.
I can't stop the debugger on breakpoints when they're in a module other than the one where I'm running the debugger. On the other hand, it works very well in the module where I run the debogger.
Where should I look to fix this issue?
pteric:~ $ uname -a
Linux pteric 5.14.18-100.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 12 17:38:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
pteric:~ $ pip show spyder
Name: spyder
Version: 5.5.5
Summary: The Scientific Python Development Environment
Home-page: https://www.spyder-ide.org/
Author: The Spyder Project Contributors
Author-email: spyder.python@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/toto/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: atomicwrites, chardet, cloudpickle, cookiecutter, diff-match-patch, intervaltree, ipython, jedi, jellyfish, jsonschema, keyring, nbconvert, numpydoc, parso, pexpect, pickleshare, psutil, pygments, pylint, pylint-venv, pyls-spyder, pyqt5, pyqtwebengine, python-lsp-black, python-lsp-server, pyxdg, pyzmq, qdarkstyle, qstylizer, qtawesome, qtconsole, qtpy, rtree, setuptools, sphinx, spyder-kernels, textdistance, three-merge, watchdog
Required-by: 

EDIT:
I've just noticed that it's not just in the module where I start the debugging session that breakpoints work. In fact, breakpoints work correctly in all the traversed modules until a GUI event loop waiting for user actions (events) is started (app.exec()).
After this point, no breakpoints work ...
The same project doesn't have this issue with Pycharm or Liclipse, so I wonder if it isn't a Spyder configuration problem?
